# Vim: Is it possible to have a filtered view of a file?

Tags: vim

In a given text file, I would like to work on a "filtered view" (hiding lines with a pattern), but still to be able to edit visible lines : the filtering would only affect the **visibility** of some lines, and as soon as I would reset the filter, the hidden lines would appear again.

The feature I describe could be compared to the `&` key in the `less` command (except, of course, that `less` can't edit the file's content) :

- `&some_pattern <RETURN>` starts a new filter,
- `& <RETURN>` reset the filter.

Does such a feature exist in vim, natively or as a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually is done with *folding*; you can easily define a `'foldexpr'` that filters lines based on a regular expression match; see [Folding with Regular Expression](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding_with_Regular_Expression) for implementations.

However, a single fold line will remain for each condensed block. To do away with those, I can only think of the [NrrwRgn plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075), which transfers selected lines into a separate scratch buffer. It's usually only for a single block, but `:help NR-multi-example` suggests this works on ranges, too:

> For example before editing your config file, you decide to strip all comments
>   for making big changes but when you write your changes back, these comments
>   will stay in your file. You would do it like this: >
>
> ```
>  :v/^#/NRP
>  :NRMulti
> ```

Comment: NrrwRgn plugin put 2 info lines (begin/end) and a blank line for each separate block in the scratch buffer; but however after thinking about it, how could it work (as well with folding) without these markers? How would it react when you try to add a new line at the end or the beginning of a block? In which block should it put the line? So, there's no "perfect" solution.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with plain Vim, and it's named [folding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html).  Drew Neil has [two screencasts](http://vimcasts.org/categories/folding/) about it that you might find informative.

Comment: Folding is a very nice tool, I was thinking about it for my problem, but i don't want to see any "closed fold line"... I think it's not possible to hide them, it would be a strange behaviour for their primary goal

Comment: There is a script which uses the folding technique to filter the file (based on the word under the cursor) : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1594. Maybe there is no more elegant solution...